# Dynamic table if checkbox is unchecked add back value to the column

Tags: html, jquery

I need to add back the pay amount to the outstanding amount if the row of the checkbox is unchecked. Currently what am I facing now is when I unchecked, the outstanding amount keep decreasing and did not add back. My second row did not have pay amount but if I checked it will also keep decreasing the value. Can someone help with my coding?

**Initial version**

```
 Name | Outstanding | Pay  | 
Item 1|   20,000    | 0.00 |
Item 2|   10,000    | 0.00 |
Item 3|    3,000    | 0.00 |
```

**My expected result for checked:**

```
 Name | Outstanding |  Pay  |         |
Item 1|   14,000    | 6,000 | checked |
Item 2|    7,000    | 3,000 | checked |
Item 3|    3,000    |  0.00 |         |
```

**My expected result for unchecked:**

If unchecked, it will add back the amount to outstanding.

```
 Name | Outstanding |  Pay  |          |
Item 1|   20,000    | 6,000 | unchecked|
Item 2|    7,000    | 3,000 | checked  |
Item 3|    3,000    |  0.00 |          |
```

**Issue that I faced:**

1. I input `6,000` in first row and checked, the outstanding will become `14,000`. Then I checked the second row without input pay amount, the second row outstanding amount will also deduct and deduct again for first row. But it should not deduct again or deduct the amount since the pay amount is zero.
2. If I keep unchecked and checked, the amount will keep decrease.

```
 Name | Outstanding |  Pay  |         |
Item 1|    8,000    | 6,000 | checked |
Item 2|   18,000    |  0.00 | checked |
Item 3|    3,000    |  0.00 |         |
```

```js
$(function() {

  function calcSum(t) {
    var result = 0.00;
    var OutAmt = 0.00;
    var Amt = 0.00;
    $("tbody tr").each(function(i, r) {
      if ($('input[name="chck"]', r).is(":checked")) {
        result += parseFloat($(".payAmt", r).val());
        OutAmt += parseFloat($(".outstandingAmt", r).text().replace(/,/g, ''))
        Amt = $('.outstandingAmt', r).text((OutAmt - result).toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,'));

      }
    });
    return result;
  }

  function updateSum(tbl) {
    var t = calcSum(tbl);
    $("#txtUnappliedAmt").val(t.toFixed(2));
  }

  updateSum($("#price-list"));

  $("#price-list input").change(function() {
    updateSum($("#price-list"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="price-list">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Outstanding</th>
      <th>Pay</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="item name">Item 1</td>
      <td class="outstandingAmt">20,000.00</td>
      <td class="item price"><input class="payAmt" type="text" value="0.00"></td>

      <td><input type="checkbox" name="chck"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="item name">Item 2</td>
      <td class="outstandingAmt">10,000.00</td>
      <td class="item price"><input class="payAmt" type="text" value="0.00"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="chck"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="item name">Item 3</td>
      <td class="outstandingAmt">5,000.00</td>
      <td class="item price"><input class="payAmt" type="text" value="0.00"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="chck"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div>
  <label><b>Unapplied Amount:</b></label>
  <input type="text" id="txtUnappliedAmt" value="0.00" disabled>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do calculation of only rows where checkbox has been checked/unchecked and keep your `calcSum` function only for getting total from checked checkbox .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(function() {

  function calcSum(t) {
    var result = 0.00;
    $("tbody tr").each(function(i, r) {
      if ($('input[name="chck"]', r).is(":checked")) {
        result += parseFloat($(".payAmt", r).val());//just for total
      }
    });
    return result;
  }

  function updateSum(tbl) {
    var t = calcSum(tbl);
    $("#txtUnappliedAmt").val(t.toFixed(2));
  }

  updateSum($("#price-list"));
 //keep this on check of checkbox..
  $("#price-list input:checkbox").change(function() {
    var closest_row = $(this).closest("tr")//closest row..
    var pay_ = parseFloat($(".payAmt", closest_row).val())
    var OutAmt = parseFloat($(".outstandingAmt", closest_row).text().replace(/,/g, ''))
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $('.outstandingAmt', closest_row).text((OutAmt - pay_).toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,')); //deduce
    } else {
      $('.outstandingAmt', closest_row).text((OutAmt + pay_).toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,')); //add
    }
    updateSum($("#price-list"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="price-list">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Outstanding</th>
      <th>Pay</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="item name">Item 1</td>
      <td class="outstandingAmt">20,000.00</td>
      <td class="item price"><input class="payAmt" type="text" value="0.00"></td>

      <td><input type="checkbox" name="chck"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="item name">Item 2</td>
      <td class="outstandingAmt">10,000.00</td>
      <td class="item price"><input class="payAmt" type="text" value="0.00"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="chck"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="item name">Item 3</td>
      <td class="outstandingAmt">5,000.00</td>
      <td class="item price"><input class="payAmt" type="text" value="0.00"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="chck"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div>
  <label><b>Unapplied Amount:</b></label>
  <input type="text" id="txtUnappliedAmt" value="0.00" disabled>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Swati, I have two situation that I faced which is the row checked and if I change the payAmount it will also update the outstanding amount and the unapplied amount.  Others is if the payAmount have value, it will auto checked and calculate. I able to auto checked but the calculation for outstanding amount calculate wrongly. [My latest js fiddle for auto checked](https://jsfiddle.net/pze46qmr/3/)

Comment: Hi, how should i test that ie : Can you guide me to see that result ?

Comment: Sure. https://i.postimg.cc/FzrXrx6n/case4.png (My expected result)

Comment: So , the problem is with outstanding amount . This is because you are changing your original price itself . Quick fix will be  saving original value in data-attribute and then whenever you check/unchecked use that original value  to do your calculation i.e : [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7ouLep9v/) .

Comment: So how could I do for update the amount when I have enter 6,000 amount and checked the row, then I change the amount from 6,000 to 3,000 then it will update amount.

Comment: Currently I solved for the situation 2 but for situation 1 still can't solve. [My latest js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bqj934hg/)

Comment: But , Its working for me even for first option as well in that fiddle link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234216/discussion-between-swati-and-esther123).

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  function getPrice(row) {
    var txt = $(".price", row).text().slice(1);
    var p = parseFloat(txt);
    return p;
  }

  function calcSum(t) {
    var result = 0.00;
    $("tbody tr", t).each(function(i, r) {
      if ($("input", r).is(":checked")) {
        result += getPrice(r);
      }
    });
    return result;
  }

  function updateSum(tbl) {
    var t = calcSum(tbl);
    $("tfoot .total.price", tbl).html("$" + t.toFixed(2));
  }

  updateSum($("#price-list"));

  $("#price-list input").change(function() {
    updateSum($("#price-list"));
  });
});
```

```css
#price-list {
  width: 240px;
}

#price-list thead th {
  width: 33%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#price-list tfoot td {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="price-list">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="item name">Item 1</td>
      <td class="item price">$3.00</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" checked /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="item name">Item 2</td>
      <td class="item price">$4.00</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" checked /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="item name">Item 3</td>
      <td class="item price">$5.00</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" checked /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>Sum</td>
      <td class="total price">$0.00</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```